# Network bonding mode balance-rr / 802.3ad layer3+4 on Linux

Tags: load-balancing, bonding, round-robin

What is the difference between **balance-rr** and **802.3ad** *with xmit_hash_policy set to layer3+4*.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt

> `layer3+4`: This algorithm is not fully 802.3ad compliant.  A
> single TCP or UDP conversation containing both
> fragmented and unfragmented packets will see packets
> striped across two interfaces.  This may result in out
> of order delivery.  Most traffic types will not meet
> this criteria, as TCP rarely fragments traffic, and
> most UDP traffic is not involved in extended
> conversations.  Other implementations of 802.3ad may
> or may not tolerate this noncompliance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**802.3ad** with xmit_hash_policy set to layer3+4 is a bonding mode that is one of the standard, sensible, and widely used ones. Like many others it doesn't allow >100% throughput for a single TCP connection. In practice the fragmented packet disclaimer you quoted is not relevant as far as I've seen.

**balance-rr** is a very specific and rarely used balancing mode. It's mainly useful for a dedicated backup-restore subnet. When maintained with the joint network and system admin staff, with the switch specifically set up and all the servers/routers specifically set up, with a little bit of testing, you could achieve >100% throughput for a single TCP connection. Don't expect 200% though. (Remember to test both directions, unless you like your restores very slow). If a link gets down, the remaining one(s) will function.

You've already linked to a detailed technical description, so I've figured out you'd like a high-level answer.

Comment: Not 200% but very close: https://pastebin.com/XD5vmTr5 - balance_rr is a massive improvement for single TCP connections compared to LACP.

Answer (score 0):

Link aggregation group (LAG) is used not only to increase bandwidth, also it used to link backup. If one link of LAG will down the balance-rr  LAG won't work properly, but the 802.3ad LAG will work good with reduced bandwidth.

The balance-rr  LAG allows to use full LAG's bandwidth for one TCP/UDP connection, but the 802.3ad  LAG allows to use only one link bandwidth for it. The balance-rr  LAG isn't support backup-restore. It perfect works with Cisco Etherchannel LAG. Many Cisco switches support only Etherchannel LAG and don't support 802.3ad LACP.

Comment: "_Many Cisco switches support only Etherchannel LAG and don't support 802.3ad LACP._ As  far as I know, Cisco switches do support both PAgP _and_ LACP. LACP is configured on an interface with the `channel-group <group> mode [active|passive]` command.

Comment: Only 65xx and some others, but they didn't support `layer3+4` hash.

Comment: That is completely incorrect. All current models support LACP. I think you are working from very, very old information.

Comment: I didn't say about only newest equipment. But new 2960 Catalist can't work with LACP `fast mode` or with `layer3+4` load balance. PAgP works only between Cisco equipments.